# What term means “place where we can learn and share knowledge"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a term which means "place where we can learn and share knowledge about almost anything"?

Comment: Educational institute? *joke: Stack Exchange?*

Comment: Agreed with @Tim: *school*.

Comment: I would say "life".

Comment: an academy ... name comes from "The Academy", the garden where Plato taught.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're in luck because we have one right here on the Stack Exchange!

A word you could use is **forum**.

This word has come to most popularly refer to online chat-rooms, however its origins lie in ancient Rome when forums were places people went to meet and discuss business ideas.

It can also still be used to denote places where people meet to discuss a plethora of different matters.

For more information: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forum

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I agree with *Dog Lover*'s "institution". When you think about institution you can easily think about a mental institution, and there's the famous "Marriage is a beautiful institution, but who wants to live in an institution?" So I think institution is too broad.

When you take the words "learning", "share knowledge" and especially "almost anything" you automatically get to the word **"university"**. Note that it has the same root as "universal", and indeed from its origins it was a place where "everything" would be taught.

Answer (score -1):

The best word that comes to mind is "institution".

From Dictionary.com:

> **institution**
>
> an organization, establishment, foundation, society, or the like, devoted to the promotion of a particular cause or program, especially one of a public, educational, or charitable character.

Other suitable words include:

- academy
- establishment (Possibly. Would be best to add "educational".)
- institute
- school
- university
- college

Comment: Well.... One does need to be a little wary of using "institution".

Comment: @HotLicks - Indeed! The connotation had crossed my mind, but I decided it was still the best-fitting word.

Comment: Fits a lot of people here, certainly.